# How to get difference bettwen 2 dates in weeks with Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

In laravel 6 app I want to get difference bettwen 2 dates in weeks: if dates break a week get value > 0

I see diffInWeeks method written here : https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-week

Having 2 dates I make :

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($eventItem['at_time']));//->format($date_format);
\Log::info('$startDate ::');
\Log::info(print_r($startDate, true));
$offset_x= $startDate->dayOfWeek;

$endDate = $startDate->add($eventItem['duration'] . ' minutes');
\Log::info('-1  $endDate::' . print_r($endDate, true));
$diff_in_weeks=  $startDate->diffInWeeks($endDate);
\Log::info('-3 $diff_in_weeks  ::' . print_r($diff_in_weeks, true));
```

In logs :

```
[2020-04-20 06:16:56] local.INFO: $startDate ::  
[2020-04-20 06:16:56] local.INFO: Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2018-02-01 09:08:39.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)

[2020-04-20 06:16:56] local.INFO: -1  $endDate::Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2018-02-22 04:28:39.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)

[2020-04-20 06:16:56] local.INFO: -3 $diff_in_weeks  ::0
```

But in output above I see that with 21 days difference $diff_in_weeks == 0

I tried to replace dates:

```
$diff_in_weeks= $endDate->diffInWeeks($startDate);
```

and got 0 anyway...

Which is the valid way ?

Thanks!

Comment: When you did `$startDate->add($eventItem['duration'] . ' minutes')` you were updating the 'startDate' which means both dates are the same. You could try instead, `$startDate->copy()->add($eventItem['duration'] . ' minutes')` and see the diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a week is 7 days, so instead you can use Carbon's diffInDays() method (to see how many days are in the period) and divide the result by 7, then you can cast it to int

update:
it's as 'Mohammad Hosseini' said, so to avoid changing the original value you can use CarbonImmutable in your class like so:

```
use Carbon\CarbonImmutable;
```

instead of using:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

and you won't have to change anything in your code

Answer (score 2):

Because when you use `$endDate = $startDate->add($eventItem['duration'] . ' minutes');`
The start date ($startDate) also changes its value, and from that line, the start date has a new value, and in fact the start date is equal to the end date. So your solution is:

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($eventItem['at_time']));


$endDate = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($eventItem['at_time']))->add($eventItem['duration'] . ' minutes');


$diff_in_weeks=  $startDate->diffInWeeks($endDate);
```